# How to Automate Tests using Protractor with Appium and IOS-Simulator on MAC

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor, appium

Do you know if there is possible way to run automated tests using Protractor (or WebDriverJS) on MAC with Appium and IOS-Simulator?

We didn't succeed to run tests with the following config file, otherwise it works fine with Selenium 2.0 - WebDriver,

The following is the config file (protractor):

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://192.168.8.2:4723/wd/hub', 
   specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
    'appium-version': '1.3.7',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '8.2',
    deviceName: 'iPhone 5s'
  },  
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000  
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my config file i'm using protractor with appium :

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 600000,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'testsuite/test3.js'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari',
   'appium-version': '1.4.13',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '9.3',
    deviceName: 'iPad Air',
    'autoWebview' : true         
},

  chromeOnly: false,

  baseUrl: 'putyoururlhere',

  framework:[
    'jasmine'
  ],

jasmineNodeOpts: { 

    defaultTimeoutInterval:1000000
}         
};
```